# JDK 10 modules and sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, docker, java-module, java-10

I use to run my application on the `openjdk:10-slim` docker image and everything was working fine.

Then I migrated to a custom JDK built with Jlink using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:10-jdk-slim AS jdkBuilder

RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink \
--module-path /opt/jdk/jmods \
--verbose \
--add-modules java.base,java.logging,java.xml,java.xml.bind,java.sql,jdk.unsupported,java.naming,java.desktop,java.management,java.security.jgss,java.security.sasl,jdk.crypto.cryptoki,jdk.crypto.ec,java.instrument,jdk.management.agent \
--output /opt/jdk-minimal \
--compress 2 \
--no-header-files


FROM debian:9-slim
COPY --from=jdkBuilder /opt/jdk-minimal /opt/jdk-minimal

ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-minimal
COPY target/*.jar /opt/

CMD $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /opt/*.jar
```

That mostly works fine too expect for when I use the AWS S3 SDK in which case I get the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm guessing that those certificates (or ways of accessing them) are provided by one missing package which I'm not including.

I did some digging and couldn't find any information about that. I tried adding any module that could be related to security or SSL but I without luck.

Has anyone encountered this issue and know which module need to be added?
As a workaround I reverted back to `openjdk:10-slim` but I would like to use `jlink` as it makes my image smaller

Comment: try copying cacerts from openjdk:10-slim to JDK

Comment: Good idea let me try

Comment: @FranMontero that worked thanks. Do you want to write an answer or shall I do one with the changes I made to the docker file?

Comment: just wrote one :D. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception suggests that your environment is missing some root certificates.

Try copying `cacerts` from `openjdk:10-slim` to JDK you are using.

Comment: For reference I did that by adding the following line to the Dockerfile `COPY --from=jdkBuilder /docker-java-home/lib/security/cacerts /opt/jdk-minimal/lib/security/cacerts`